# iPhone Background Image for Table Cell

Tags: iphone, background-image, tablecell

How can I make the background of the accessory clear? I've managed to set the rest of the elements to `[UIColor clearcolor]` but it doesn't work for the accessory...

Here's what my progress looks like:

[image]

```
    [self.accessoryView setOpaque: NO];

    self.accessoryView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon.png"]];

    self.accessoryView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Thanks for any help you guys can offer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried

```
cell.accessoryView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: try  accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone; before setting the background

Comment: Yeah that removes it and give the appearance I'm after however it removes the "arrow" as well. I suppose it doesn't really matter that much. Thanks for your help

Comment: you can always put an image that represents this arrow :) please vote for my answer :P